# Commuting normal matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, operator-theory

Suppose $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are normal. Show that if $AB=BA$, then $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Assuming the Spectral Theorem this is not a hard proof. Is it possible to prove this without assuming it?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are diagonalisable, and $AB=BA$ then $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalisable, so all you need is that normal matrices are diagonalisable.

Comment: To prove that they are simultaneously diagonalisable, you need to prove that each of the them is diagonalisable (because commutativity doesn't imply diagonalisability). But this *is* the spectral theorem. So, yes, you may opt not to assume any knowledge in the spectral theorem, but you'll end up proving it by yourself.